# include sympy library into chaquo

Tags: sympy, chaquopy

include sympy python packages into Chaquopy:

1. I started with the example python provided by Chaquopy available at github (https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy) for Android studio 3.0.1.
2. Than I created 2 wheel files from the sympy source () files, based on python 3.6.3, see the below files that wheel generated:

                   "mpmath-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl"

                   "sympy-1.1.1-py3-none-any.whl"
3. I tried to install the above files into the build.gradle of the demo example from 1., for testing purposes I tried some of there own wheel files (that process succeeded), but could not install my own wheel files.
4. I am fairly certain that the local wheel files that I generated are placed in the proper directory, because if I change the directory in the gradle file it complains that it cannot find the file.
5. I included the wheel files in the build.gradle(Module:app) file as follows:

`python {`
// Enable and edit the following line if "python" is not on your PATH.

// buildPython "C:/Python27/python.exe"

version "3.6.3" 

// Android UI demo


`pip {`

`install "Pygments==2.2.0"   // Also used in Java API demo`

`}`


pip {

      install "wheels/mpmath-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl"

`//                install "wheels/sympy-1.1.1-py3-none-any.whl"`
 //                install "numpy==1.9.2"

`//                install "numpy==1.14.0"`
}

6. When created the build gradle generates the following error:

sympy-1.1.1-py3-none-any.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
Exit status 1

:app:generatePy2DebugPythonRequirements FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:generatePy2DebugPythonRequirements'.

  > Process 'command 'python'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

7 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 6 up-to-date

Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

sympy and mpmath have now been added to the Chaquopy wheel repository (https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/20), so you don't need to build your own anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Did some further investigation and did see that I somehow compiled for Py2, while my wheel files where version 3 changing this resulted in a correct executable.

It did run into a different issue, while the mpmath module could be imported into the interactive python console (part of the demo app), the sympy module gave an error:

ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'distutils'

Let me know if anyone ran into a similar problem!

Comment: The missing distutils module is fixed in Chaquopy 1.2.0 (https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/20).